# Import errors in virtual venv

Tags: python, docker, airflow, python-venv

Sorry if there is a simple question somewhere. I have checked numerous posts and wasn't able to find a solution that would work.

I am playing with Airflow in Docker and have created the project with the following structure:

```
/airflow-demo
    /venv
    /logs
    /dags
        some_dag_that_uses_custom_hook.py
    /plugins
        /hooks
            __init__.py
            /custom
                __init__.py
                custom_hook.py
```

In the some_dag_that_uses_custom_hook.py I do import like this:

`from hooks.custom.custom_hook import CustomHook`

When I run the DAG (Airflow 2.3.2 running in Docker), it produces the result I need. So clearly, in the container, all imports are working fine.

In my local environment (I am using venv), however, I have an import error. Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'custom'.

Can anyone help me understand how to properly fix this issue?

I am expecting to be able to use imports that would work for Airflow running in Docker and for local venv environment.

I have tried to modify the PATH variable to include the folder on the local virtual environment PATH, but it seems to give no results.

I have modified the activate.bat file by adding this line to the PATH:

`%VIRTUAL_ENV%\plugins\hooks;%VIRTUAL_ENV%\plugins`

After deactivation and activation, imports are still in red.

The imports are okay if I start them from the plugins folder, but then they fail when Airflow is running in Docker with Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plugins'.

Comment: "I have tried to modify the PATH variable" PATH or PYTHONPATH?  Those are different variables with different meanings

Comment: Hi @erik258, I was changing the PATH variable.

Comment: That's the wrong one.  PATH controls how the system finds executables; PYTHONPATH controls how python finds modules.

Comment: @erik258 Thank you! It was the problem. I was modifying the wrong ENV Variable!